# ADODB Recordset not able to extract the 'XMLData' (xml format data) from SQL database

Tags: vbscript, qtp, adodb, recordset, testcomplete

I have a SQL table which is containing some xml data like below -

***xmlData***

I wrote a VBS code which is extract all the SQL column data excluding "XMLData"

my Dummy VBS Code -

Sub getdata()

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Connection String"

Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sqlquery = "select * from TableName WHERE IsExecute = 'Yes'"
Set rs = objConnection.Execute(sqlquery)

If Recordset.EOF Then 
msgbox "There are no records to retrieve; Check that you have the correct job number."
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof

field = Recordset("xmlData")

if field <> "" then
    Msgbox field
end if

Recordset.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub

Need a help to get xml format data from SQL database.
like -

***xmlData
<

EndResync/> ***

Thanks

RaviK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve XML data from SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869373/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I have an observation here, VBS(Recordset) not able to extract the data if SQL Column is "nvarchar(max)" type is defined.